# Jquery inside PHP loop with PHP values as ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, unique

I'm using a Bootstrap multiselect plugin (https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/). The documentation says to call the plugin to the forms select id by the following:

```
$('#example').multiselect();
```

However my page is a timetable with multiple cells that are actually generated by a loop statement. Days (Mon-Sun) looped by how many units are in the database. Inside each box, is a separate form which works fine. Now i've wanted to add the multiselect plugin to add a select dropdown into the forms however I can't seem to call the plugin.
I have a $i value that increases on each loop but this will only loop the amount of times a vehicle has been added (5 vehicles, 5 loops etc.). So if I have ms_ this will work, however only for the first column as thats where it stops being unique. I have another value of $thisdate which gives me the date the current cell is on. So technically I thought I should be able to have the following:

```
<?php
$currentlocation = $i . $thisdate;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ms-<?php echo ''.$currentlocation.''; ?>').multiselect();
</script>
```

This doesn't work. However the below does, but only for the first column.

```
<?php
 $currentlocation = $i;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#ms-<?php echo ''.$currentlocation.''; ?>').multiselect();
</script>
```

Or this which works for the top column

```
<?php
 $currentlocation = $thisdate;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#ms-<?php echo ''.$currentlocation.''; ?>').multiselect();
</script>
```

$i and $thisdate together would be the unique cell value.

[image]

**EDIT: This was fixed by using** `$('.example').multiselect();`

Comment: give all the select elements in each cell form the same class and then call `$('.example').multiselect();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m1nra8uh/

Comment: Gesset creating must select in the loop is not at all recommended and is a bad approach. So please recheck and reconsider your answer selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working perfectly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">

<?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i ++) { 
    $date=date("Y-m-d"); 
?>

<div class="">
    <strong>Select Language:</strong>
    <select id="ms-<?php echo $i?>-<?php echo $date; ?>" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="sql">SQL</option>
        <option value="jquery">Jquery</option>
        <option value=".net">.Net</option>
    </select>
  
</div>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {  
var i = '<?php echo $i; ?>'; 
var current_date = '<?php echo (string) $date; ?>'; 
      $(`#ms-${i}-${current_date}`).multiselect({
          includeSelectAllOption: true,
        });
    });
</script>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's a worse idea to add multi-select in the loop, while it can be done in a single statement without a loop. Not recommended at all. Please check my answer for more details.

Comment: David F It's a worse idea to add multi-select in the loop, while it can be done in a single statement without a loop. Not recommended at all. Please check my answer for more details.

Comment: You didn't understand the question exactly.

Comment: I have understood it exactly. multi-select can be applicable based on class as well. so no need to do it in the loop.  https://jsfiddle.net/m1nra8uh/